# Parsing data from structured document with ambiguous labeling

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, parsing, plaintext

I am attempting to move legal documents from ancient SGML files into a database. Using regular expressions in java, I have had pretty good luck. However, I have run into a slight problem. It appears that the labeling for each part of the document is not standard between documents. For instance, the most common labeling is:

```
(<numeric>)
    (<alpah>)
        (<ROMAN>)
            (<ALPHA>)
```

Ex. (1)(a)(I)(A)

However, there are other documents that have variations, with the possibility of () being thrown in there. My current algorithm has hard coded RegExs that match each element at each level. But I need a way to dynamically set the label type for each level as I work my way through the document.

Has anyone come across an issue like this? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here are the RegExs I use to parse out the different items:

```
Section: ^<tab>(<b>)?\d{1,4}(\.\d+)?-((\d{1,4}(\.\d+)?)(-|\.)?){3}
SubSection: \.?\s*(<\/b>|<tab>|^)\s*\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)\s+($|<b>|[A-Z"]|\([a-z](.\d+)?\)\s*(\((XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(\.\d+)?\)\s*(\([A-Z](.\d+)?\))?)?\s*.)
Paragraph: (^|<tab>|\s+|\(\d+(\.\d+)?\)\s+)\([a-z](.\d+)?\)(\s+$|\s+<b>|\s+[A-Z"]|\s*\((XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(\.\d+)?\)(\([A-Z](.\d+)?\))?\s*[A-Z"]?)
SubParagraph: (\)|<tab>|<\/b>)\s*\((XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(\.\d+)?\)\s+($|[A-Z"<]|\([A-Z](.\d+)?\)\s*[A-Z"])
SubSubParagraph: (<tab>|\)\s*)\([A-Z](.\d+)?\)\s+([A-Z"]|$)
```

And here's some example text. I misspoke earlier. Although the ultimate source of the data is in SGML, I am parsing something slightly different. Besides having style tags, it is more or less plain text.

```
<tab><b>SECTION 5.</b>  In Colorado Revised Statutes, 13-5-142, <b>amend</b> (1)
introductory portion, (1)(b), and (3)(b)(II) as follows:

<tab><b>13-5-142.  National instant criminal background check system - reporting.</b>
(1)  On and after March 20, 2013, the state court administrator shall send electronically
the following information to the Colorado bureau of investigation created pursuant to
section 24-33.5-401, referred to in this section as the "bureau":

<tab>(b)  The name of each person who has been committed by order of the court to the
custody of the office of behavioral health in the department of human services pursuant
to section 27-81-112 or 27-82-108; and

<tab>(3)  The state court administrator shall take all necessary steps to cancel a record
made by the state court administrator in the national instant criminal background check
system if:

<tab>(b)  No less than three years before the date of the written request:

<tab>(II)  The period of commitment of the most recent order of commitment or
recommitment expired, or a court entered an order terminating the person's incapacity or
discharging the person from commitment in the nature of habeas corpus, if the record in
the national instant criminal background check system is based on an order of
commitment to the custody of the office of behavioral health in the department of human
services; except that the state court administrator shall not cancel any record pertaining to
a person with respect to whom two recommitment orders have been entered pursuant to
section 27-81-112 (7) and (8), or who was discharged from treatment pursuant to section
27-81-112 (11) on the grounds that further treatment is not likely to bring about
significant improvement in the person's condition; or
```

Comment: Does the SGML comply with a schema (DTD)? In general, it would be best to use standard parsers instead of regular expressions when it come to parsing structured data.

Comment: I should have mentioned the SGML is poorly structured. From what I can tell, the developer of these documents defined each item using styles. There aren't may descriptive tags for each item.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of properly and improperly formed SGML and provide examples of the output you want? Also, could you post the regexes you've tried so that we can 1) review them 2) edit it to work (if possible) and 3) not try something you've already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement of the problem is vague, so the only possible answers are general approaches. I've worked on imprecisely formatted document conversions like this.

A tool from CS that can help is a state machine. It's appropriate if you can detect (e.g. with regex) that the format is changing to new convention. This changes the state, which in this case is equivalent to the translator to use on the current and following chunks of text. It remains in effect until the next state change.  Overall the algorithm looks like this:

```
translator = DEFAULT 
while (chunks of input remain) {
  chunk = GetNextChunkOfInput // a line, paragraph, etc.
  new_translator = ScanChunkForStateChange(chunk, translator)
  if (new_translator != null) translator = new_translator // found a state change!
  print(translator.Translate(chunk))  // use the translator on the chunk
}
```

Within this framework, it's a fiddly process to design translators and the state change predicate. All you can hope to do is try, examine output, and fix problems, repeating until you can't get any better. At that point you've probably discovered a maximal structure in the input, so algorithms that work with pattern matching alone (without trying to model semantics e.g. with an AI) won't get you too much farther.

Comment: Thanks Gene. I tweaked my algorithm to more closely resemble your pseudo code and am getting better results. Like you said, I should be able to tweak it to get better results.

Answer (score 0):

The text snippet you posted can be parsed and structured by an SGML parser with custom grammar rules in a `DOCTYPE` aka DTD (assuming `<tab>` in your example represents an actual `tab` start-element tag rather than a TAB character). I've taken your snippet, stored it in a file named `data.ent`, and then created the following SGML file, `doc.sgm`, referencing it:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ELEMENT doc O O (tab)+>
    <!ELEMENT tab - O (((b,c?)|c),text)>
    <!ELEMENT text O O (#PCDATA|b)+>
    <!ELEMENT b - - (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT c - - (#PCDATA)>
    <!ENTITY data SYSTEM "data.ent">
    <!ENTITY startc "<c>">
    <!ENTITY endc "</c>">
    <!SHORTREF intab "(" startc ")" endc>
    <!USEMAP intab tab>
    <!USEMAP #EMPTY text>
]>
&data
```

The result of parsing your data with these DTD rules (using `osgmlnorm doc.sgm` on the command line) is as follows:

```
<DOC>
  <TAB>
    <B>SECTION 5.</B>
    <TEXT>In Colorado Revised Statutes, 13-5-142, <B>amend</B> (1)
      introductory portion, (1)(b), and (3)(b)(II) as follows:
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
  <TAB>
    <B>13-5-142.  National instant criminal background check system
      reporting.</B>
    <C>1</C>
    <TEXT>On and after March 20, 2013, the state court administrator
      shall send electronically the following information to the
      Colorado bureau of investigation created pursuant to section
      24-33.5-401, referred to in this section as the "bureau":
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
  <TAB>
    <C>b</C>
    <TEXT>The name of each person who has been committed by order
      of the court to the custody of the office of behavioral health
      in the department of human services pursuant to section 27-81-112
      or 27-82-108; and
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
  <TAB>
    <C>3</C>
    <TEXT>The state court administrator shall take all necessary steps
      to cancel a record made by the state court administrator in the
      national instant criminal background check system if:
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
  <TAB>
    <C>b</C>
    <TEXT>No less than three years before the date of the written
      request:
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
  <TAB>
    <C>II</C>
    <TEXT>The period of commitment of the most recent order of
      commitment or recommitment expired, or a court entered an order
      terminating the person's incapacity or discharging the person
      from commitment in the nature of habeas corpus, if the record in 
      the national instant criminal background check system is based on
      an order of commitment to the custody of the office of behavioral
      health in the department of human services; except that the state
      court administrator shall not cancel any record pertaining to
      a person with respect to whom two recommitment orders have been
      entered pursuant to section 27-81-112 (7) and (8), or who was
      discharged from treatment pursuant to section 27-81-112 (11) on
      the grounds that further treatment is not likely to bring about
      significant improvement in the person's condition; or
    </TEXT>
  </TAB>
</DOC>
```

Explanation:

- the SGML DTD I created uses SGML tag inference to infer a made-up `DOC`
  element as document element, as well as artificial `TEXT` and `C` elements;
  the main purpose is to impose document structure as a sequence of
  `TAB` elements, each containing a section identifier (such as
  `<b>SECTION 5.</b>` or `(c)`), followed by section body text
- I've also made up an ad-hoc element `C` for wrapping section identifier
  text put in braces (`(` and `)` characters); the start- end end-element
  tags for `C` are automatically inserted by an SGML processor due to the
  DTD's `SHORTREF` mapping rules; these tell SGML that within a `TAB`
  element, SGML should replace all `(` characters by the value of the
  `startc` entity (which expands to `<C>`), and all `)` characters by the
  value of the `endc` entity (which expands to `</C>`)
- `<!USEMAP #EMPTY text>` switches off expansion of parentheses in the
  `TEXT` body part of a `TAB` section such that references `(7)`, `(8)` in
  body text don't get changed (though these could be changed into HTML-like
  links as well using SGML)

In case your use of `<tab>` represents a TAB (ASCII 9) character, SGML can handle that as well, eg. by translating TAB characters into `<TAB>` tags using `SHORTREF` rules similar to the ones shown.

Note you need to have the `osgmlnorm` program installed; it can be installed using `sudo apt-get install opensp` if you're on Ubuntu, and similar on other Linux variants and Mac OS. For your application, you'll maybe want to use the `osx` program (also part of OpenSP) to output the normalized parsing result to XML (though the output shown above already can be parsed as XML), and then use Java XML APIs to process the structured content to your needs.